# calling Delphi function from SphinxC--

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009

i have a Delphi function declared like this

```
function strcspn(s1, s2: PAnsiChar): Cardinal;  cdecl;
```

i want call it from SphinxC-- , the problem is SphinxC-- need the name of strcspn without any decoration.

SO how to forc Delphi to set that in obj file?

I will ask it with more details.

I am using SphinxC-- language , that you can consider it as a mix of Masm assembler and c language. it can prcduce OMF file format.

I successfully mix it with C++Builder by linking code compiled with SphinxC-- and code compiled with bcc32 (c++Builder compiler). by using extern "C" term in c++ code that tells bcc32 to unmangeled function name ,also with using -u- (bcc32 command line otpion) which tells bcc32 to preduce function name without prefix underscore.

now i have some delphi code that i want to mix it with my SphinXC-- code ,
just like what i have done with c++Builder.

so my question is how to force delphi compiler dcc32 to preduce unmangeled function name ?

Edited again:

here are my commend line for bcc32,dcc32,ilink32

for dc32

```
dcc32.exe -DMSWINDOWS -JPHNE -I"mypath/include" -U"mypath\lib" -U"mypath\units"  mfiley.pas
```

for bcc32

```
bcc32.exe -u- -DDEBUG;NO_STRICT -D_RTLDLL;USEPACKAGES  -k  -c -tWM -v- -Vw  -W- -Par -M -Hc -P myfile.cpp
```

for ilink32

```
ilink32 -v -Gn -G8 ........ etc
```

Comment: What is SphinxC--? I doubt you can expect to compile Delphi code into an object file and statically link it. `strcspn` is a C standard library function. Why are you implementing it in Delphi? In short, it seems likely that you don't have a clear understanding of what you are doing, and you certainly have not communicated anything answerable in this question. Please make an effort to express clearly what you are doing, and what your question is, in an edit.

Comment: Ok David,  I am trying to mix my best programming language  SphinxC--and extend it's to use C++Builder , Delphi , and it's lnker.  SphinxC-- is a middel point of c and asm. So i can call C++Builder functions by using extern "C" term and -u- commend line options , my question is how to make that with Delphi to preduce un mangeled functions name , hope that ,it is clear now. any help please?

Comment: Not even remotely clear. Please don't ask the question in comments. Please edit the question to make it very clear what you are asking.

Comment: It's still very far from clear. The Delphi compiler is not bcc32. That's the C++ Builder compiler. Please can you pay some serious attention to the details.

Comment: Presumably you meant dcc32 right? Perhaps you could show the command line you use to compile.

Comment: sorry , it misstyping i ment DCC32 instead of bcc32 , i will correct it

Comment: But I still don't hold out much hope for you. How are you going to manage without the Delphi RTL? You've no chance of success with any real world Delphi code.

Comment: The problem is that any non-trivial Delphi code needs its RTL. How will it link to it?

Comment: You are not going to be able to use any Delphi object file in any other language. Delphi's DCUs are not compatible with any other linker; C++ Builder's linker is customized to do so, because it was specifically designed to do so by Borland (who owned them both) so that C++ Builder could use Delphi's VCL. SphinxC (whatever that is) wasn't designed with Delphi's specialized object files in mind. And *please* put at least a minimal amount of effort into formatting your posts in the future. You made no effort to do so (a single <pre> (without closure) and a single <code> (unclosed)).

Comment: Have you tried compiling the Delphi code in C++ Builder?

Comment: @Jens How would that help?

Answer (score 1):

> My question is how to force Delphi compiler dcc32 to produce unmangled function names?

That is not possible. If you wish to have unmangled function names, then you would need to use a tool like [objconv](http://www.agner.org/optimize/) to modify the names post-compile.

A far bigger problem is that any serious real world Delphi code is going to require the Delphi RTL, and I see very little hope of you being able to link that to your C++ project statically. Realistically, to mix C++ and Delphi code in the same module requires a tool that has intimate knowledge of both languages, and that tool is C++-Builder.

Answer (score -1):

already have C++Builder , so using Delphi units with C++ is very easy. i will try using objconv. My last solution is to call delphi stuff from C++Builder helper function.

something like this

```
   Delphi side
   function DelhpFunc(s1, s2: PAnsiChar): integer;  cdecl;
   .....
   .....
```

C++Builder side

include <....hpp> headre file that made by Delphi

extern "C" 
    {
      __declspec(naked)  int  helperFunc()
       {
          asm {
            jmp DelhpFunc
           }
       }
    };

`SphinxC-- side

extern int cdecl helperFunc(char* s1,char* s2);

main()
{
   helperFunc("hello","there");
}`

Comment: This doesn't seem to be related to the question that was asked. To recap, the question was: *My question is how to force Delphi compiler dcc32 to produce unmangled function names?* Please can you try to answer the question that was asked.

Comment: ok , when i asked my question my intinetion was force Dlphie to preduce unmangled name so that i can later call that function easily from SphinxC-- , due to there was no option to unmangled name i discoverd the above solution for my problem , may be useful for someone else.

Comment: This isn't about solving your problems. It's about answering the question asked. Please read the [help]. If you engaged more, then we'd be more keen to go the extra mile for you.